# What Am I doing wrong in scraping. Returns no value for my code

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code works for one site and not another site. Can some one help me out.

```py
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 URL = "https://www.homedepot.com/s/311256393"
 page = requests.get(URL)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
 results = soup.find(id="root")
 print(results.prettify())
```

Where as below code shows output, is the any difference on website?

```py
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 URL = "https://realpython.github.io/fake-jobs/"
 page = requests.get(URL)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
 results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")
 print(results.prettify())
```

Comment: Have you had a look at your soup? `<h1>Access Denied</h1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http://www.homedepot.com/s/311256393" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.548f1402.1636964652.c6cda48`

Comment: Thanks, so you mean I can't scrape this site, Correct? @HedgeHog

Comment: As often, it depends - Find an `api`, use `selenium`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing The Home Depot you need to use proxies (if your IP is outside the US, otherwise it will throw an *Access denied* error) and parse the data from their GraphQL API (`Dev Tools -> Network -> Fetch\XHR -> find appropriate name -> Headers (opened tab on the right after clicking on the name) -> URL`) and make a request to appropriate URL address.

Then use [JSON Response Content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) via `requests` library: `requests.get("URL").json()` which will decode JSON string to a Python dictionary, so *example code* would look something like this:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
    # additional headers if response is not 200 (look inside "Headers tab in Devtools")
}

response = requests.post('URL', headers=headers).json()
 
some_variable = response['some_dict_key_from_response']
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with bypassing blocks, you can get the desired output by using [The Home Depot Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/home-depot-search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to deal with blocks as mentioned above, figure out how to scale the number of requests (*if needed*), and there's no need to maintain it over time (*if something in the HTML will be changed*). Check out the [playground with a product you were looking for](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=home_depot_product&product_id=311256393).

Example code to integrate and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Home-Depot-Product#main.py):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), 
  "engine": "home_depot_product",  #                                ↓↓↓
  "product_id": "311256393"        # https://www.homedepot.com/s/311256393 ←
                                   #                                ↑↑↑
}                          

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

title = results["product_results"]["title"]
link = results["product_results"]["link"]
price = results["product_results"]["price"]
rating = results["product_results"]["rating"]

print(title, link, price, rating, sep="\n")


# actual JSON response is much bigger
'''
20 in. x 20 in. Palace Tile Outdoor Throw Pillow with Fringe
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-20-in-x-20-in-Palace-Tile-Outdoor-Throw-Pillow-with-Fringe-7747-04413111/311256393
19.98
5.0
'''
```

A quick glance at available `product_results`:

```py
for key in results["product_results"]:
    print(key, sep="\n")


'''
product_id
title
description
link
upc
model_number
favorite
rating
reviews
price
highlights
brand
images
bullets
specifications
fulfillment
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Comment: @Dilli, glad that it helped you somehow! :-)